# Lottie file deformation

Tags: android, lottie

Some of lottie file animation get deform when use them on android. Is there problem in there usage or that animation is bad. The animations looks good on lottiefile website.
https://lottiefiles.com/1844-timer

[image: here is my screenshot from that animation]

here is my xml that I use other animations of lottie like this they work perfect.

```xml
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/lottie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
            app:lottie_fileName="count_down.json"
            app:lottie_loop="false" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "deformed". Can you share a screeshot? You can also try to set a scale type (e.g. android:scaleType="centerCrop") to the LottieView..

Comment: @W0rmH0le screenshot added.yes I tried centerCrop and all other scale types

Comment: Humm it seems a problem with the animation since only a specific item of the composition is misaligned. Did you try to use a different type of scale? center, centerInside, centerCrop.. Maybe, some of them can fix the position of that layer

Comment: @W0rmH0le yes I use but none them dosen't help

Comment: Please, share your layout and how you start the animation. I tested that same file and it is working fine for me

Comment: @W0rmH0le realy??? it's fine?? how it can be?? i haven't access my code now. but I can say you it's very simple and I don't add any thing to it.a simple linear layout that have LottieAnimationView and for start  try to use it's own auto play but nothing changed and it is still deformed

Comment: I didn't nothing special as well. It is working fine for me. That's why I requested more details

Comment: @W0rmH0le Ok, thanks man. I must try start a new and check it in that again. maybe there is problem in codes.

Answer (score 1):

**Short-answer:**

Take pre-made color palette or change the original animation’s main color in lottie editor. Creating your own custom palette distorts the animation.

**Explanation:**

I’ve had the same issue recently. It's related to the color palette changes in Lottie itself. When you pick any of the pre-made color palettes made by lottie, it should work as normal as shown on the lottie website. The issue arises when you create a custom palette, i have no experience in after effects so I cannot say why this happens but I saw that if I take a pre-made palette it works 100%, if I were to make a custom one for colors I needed the animation would become distorted.